# find and replace by using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my url to switch the contents between 2 languages

http://mydomanin.org/km/components#children-with-disablities

or

http://mydomanin.org/en/components#children-with-disablities

```
var current_url = document.URL;
var match_url = current_url.replace(/\/km/g,'/en');
console.log(match_url);
```

I  want if find `\km` will replace by `\en` and if found `\en` replaced by `\km`

How should I do this?

Comment: Read this article  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var replace = { km:"en", en:"km" };
str = str.replace(/km|en/gi, function(match){
  return replace[match];
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2624r1eo/)**